# Scala method = trait { ... } meaning

Tags: function, scala, methods, lambda, traits

I'm trying to learn Scala and the Play Framework at the same time.  Scala looks to me like it has a lot of really cool ideas, but one of my frustrations is trying to understand all of the different syntaxes for methods/functions/lambdas/anonymous functions/etc.

So I have my main application controller like so:

```
object Application extends Controller {
  def index = Action {
    Ok(views.html.index("Your new application is ready."))
  }
}
```

This tells me I have a singleton `Application` that has one method, `index`, that returns what type??  I was expecting `index` to have a definition more like:

```
def index(req: Request) : Result = { ... }
```

Looking at Play Framework's documentation, it looks as though `Action` is a trait, that transforms a request to a result, by I'm having a hard time understanding what this line is saying:

```
def index = Action { ... }
```

I come from a Java background, so I don't know what this is saying?  (this statement *feels* like it's saying "method index = [some interface Action]", which doesn't make sense to me; it seems something beautiful is happening, but it is magic to me, and I feel uneasy with magic in my code ;))

Comment: Another whack at me trying to make sense of this: is `def index = Action { ... }` akin to saying `index = new Action { _interface implementation here_ }` (e.g., anonymous interface instantiation in Java)?

Comment: I share your feeling of being syntactically overwhelmed.  A couple of tools when all else is mud: stepping with the debugger, and -Xprint:all with the compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you invoke an object as if it were a function, that's translated into a call to `apply`. I.e.:

```
foo(bar)
```

is translated into

```
foo.apply(bar)
```

So, inside `index` you are calling the `Action` object as if it were a function, which means you are *actually* calling `Action.apply`.

The return type of `index` is omitted because the compiler can infer it to be the return type of `Action.apply` (which I guess from the name is `Unit`).

Comment: Cool. Thanks for taking the time to explain. This is beginning to make sense.  Looking at this page: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.Action it appears that `Action.apply` returns `Future[SimpleResult]`?  But if I put that in my definition of `index`, it does not compile (but as you suggest, `Unit` does).  What's going on here?  Also, `Action` also defines `abstract parser: BodyParser[A]`, how come I don't need to define this method at all?

Comment: You are looking at the `Action` trait, you need to look at the `Action` object: click on the little "fold" marker on the "`t`" icon at the top left. Then you will see that `Action.apply` actually returns an `Action`.

Comment: Would I be right in thinking that he's really calling `apply` on an anonymous subclass of the Action companion that he's provided an initializer (`Ok(...)`) for?  If so, that's a lot easier for us Java-heads to get our head around.

Comment: No. There is an *object* `Action` which just happens to have the same name as the *trait* `Action`. There is no subclass or instance of this object, it already *is* an object. Having an object with the same name as a class or a trait is how Scala fakes "static" methods.

Comment: The curly braces are alternative syntax for an argument. You can pass arguments either in round parentheses or in curly braces. It's common to pass arguments which are intended as code blocks in curly braces to make them look like code blocks.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Curly braces are not an alternative of parentheses. Curly braces simply wrap a block of code and make up an expression that can be then passed as an argument.

Comment: Fascinating.  So let me step through this to make sure I understand: `def index = Action { ... }` says "index is the function returned by calling `Action.apply({...})`.  That is, the code block `{...}` is getting passed to `Action.apply`?

Comment: Which `Action.apply` incidentally returns an `Action[AnyContent]`

Comment: @Jrop Yeah... plus the fact that the argument of `Action.apply` is a by-name argument (the signature is: `final def apply(block: => Result): Action[AnyContent]` - note the arrow `=>`), which means that the argument will not be actually evaluated but passed as something lambda-like that can be evaluated later.

Comment: Thanks a bundle for your help!  I'm going to accept this as the answer, and then try to compile all of these comments into another answer, just for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

So the short answer to this question is that there's some stuff going on behind the scenes that makes the above work: namely that the compiler is inferring types, and in Scala, objects with an `apply` method can get called as if they were functions.

So what's going on here is that this code:

```
def index = Action {
  Ok("Hello World!")
}
```

...is equivalent to (or rather shorthand for) this code:

```
def index : Action[AnyContent] = Action.apply(
    (req: Request[AnyContent]) => {
        Ok(views.html.index("Hello World!"))
    } : Result
)
```

The magic is happening here: `... = Action {...}`.  `Action {...}` says "call `Action` with this anonymous function `{...}`".

Because `Action.apply` is defined as `apply(block: => Result): Action[AnyContent]`, all of the argument-/return- types can be inferred.