# What is the purpose of the annotation after equal sign?

Tags: scala, playframework

There is a val in scala that is written like this:

`val TODO = Action {
    NotImplemented[play.twirl.api.Html](views.html.defaultpages.todo())
}`

What is the purpose of the Action after the equal sign?

Comment: `Action` isn't a type annotation, it's an object. You're calling `Action.apply`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scala method = trait { ... } meaning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19963318/scala-method-trait-meaning)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's just an alternative syntax for

```
val TODO = Action(NotImplemented[play.twirl.api.Html](views.html.defaultpages.todo()))
```

which in turn is syntactic sugar for

```
val TODO = Action.apply(NotImplemented[play.twirl.api.Html](views.html.defaultpages.todo()))
```